# Podcast/voice improvement software

Tags: audio, recording

I'm running a blank here on what it is, so.. i'm hoping someone might remember. Its an application that when started has a single window you drag a wave file into, and it would automatically do some normalisation and other things, and throw back a better sounding file- its meant for use with podcasts, and i vaguely remember the name ends with 'lator'

Comment: You must mention operating system

Comment: Well, its a cross platform application.. apparently runs on most common ones. Someone got it in 1 ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Levelator®](http://www.conversationsnetwork.org/levelator)

Comment: ahh, yes! that is it.